# Access Value Type Array on View from the Model having Object Type Data Member on the Front View on ASP.NET core Project

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have an object Data Member

```
public object CheckedBaggageDetails {get; set;}
```

in Model view, which is filling in the front view through previous pages using API response in the following format

```
ValueKind = Array : "[{"passengerType":null,"value":20,"unit":"KG"},"passengerType":null,"value":20,"unit":"KG"}]"
```

Now, I want to access the **20** and **KG** from "value" and "Unit" in the Razor page view. So, How I can index the values to access the each piece of code with its property such as Value = 20 and Unit = KG.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a class so you can deserialize it from json. If you have a list of these objects, deserialize it into a list.

```
class CheckedBaggageDetails {
    public string PassengerType { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

var baggageDetails = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<CheckedBaggageDetails>>(your json string here);
```

And then access each value from the deserialized object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But I need to do all the things on view page. Please suggest the solution as per front view page.